# grep processor type in bash from lscpu

Tags: bash, grep

I need to pull the processor architecture found in the lscpu command and save it to a variable in a bash script. Something kinda like this:

```
CPU=$(lscpu | grep "x86_64")
```

Only problem is, I dont know what the result is, ie I dont know if it is x86_64 or ARM etc. Whatever the architecture is, I need to store to that variable.

Please help

*** UPDATE ***

How about for the java version command too?

java -version | grep -oP 'java version      blah'

Comment: I am sure there is some kind of combination of parameters to get the exact value without processing the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the second column of the particular line where the `Architecture:` string is found.

```
$ lscpu | grep -oP 'Architecture:\s*\K.+'
x86_64
$ CPU=$(lscpu | grep -oP 'Architecture:\s*\K.+')
```

Comment: or `lscpu | awk '/Architecture:/{print $2}'`

Comment: How about for the output for the java -version command too? java version "1.7.0_75"

Comment: it calculates the version on runtime. It can't be possible to do like the above..

Comment: Not even using a similar format? java -version | grep -oP 'java version blah'

Answer (score 0):

```
 lscpu | grep Architecture
```

OUTPUT:
Architecture:        x86_64